# Splitting string with markers in js

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a string with some markers:

```
'This is {startMarker} the string {endMarker} for {startMarker} example. {endMarker}'
```

I need to parse it into an array like :

```
[
    {marker: false, value: 'This is'},
    {marker: true,  value: 'the string'},
    {marker: false, value: 'for'},
    {marker: true, value:  'example.'}
]
```

So keep the sentence order but adding the information of the marker.
Any idea how I can achieve that ?
Thanks

Comment: It's easier for us to help with troubleshooting than it is to design entire programs. Can you  clarify what steps you tried to solve this problem yourself and what problems you ran into?

Comment: What I did is split the text until first {startMarker} then add it to the array with marker:false, then split until next {endMarker} and add it with marker:true etc until the end. But I wonder if there is a smarter solution

Comment: Is it always `<text><marker<text><marker><end>`? Can you have text before the end of the input: `<text><marker<text><marker><text><end>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```js
const my_str = 'This is {startMarker} the string {endMarker} for {startMarker} example.{endMarker}';

const my_arr = my_str.split('{endMarker}').reduce((acc, s) =>
                  s.split('{startMarker}').map((a,i) =>
                      a && acc.push({
                        marker: i ? true : false,
                        value: a.trim()}))
                      && acc,[]);
     
console.log(my_arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Only because you're a new contributor...

```
interface MarkedString {
   marker: boolean
   value: string
}

function markString(text: string): MarkedString[] {
   let match: RegExpExecArray | null

   const firstMatch = text.slice(0, text.indexOf('{') - 1)
   
   const array: MarkedString[] = firstMatch.length > 0 ? [
      { marker: false, value: firstMatch  }
   ] : []
   
   while ((match = /\{(.+?)\}/g.exec(text)) !== null) {
      if (!match) break
   
      const marker = match[0].slice(1, match[0].slice(1).indexOf('}') + 1)
   
      const markerEnd = match.index + match[0].length
   
      const value = text.slice(markerEnd ,markerEnd + text.slice(markerEnd).indexOf('{')).trim()
   
      if (value === '') break
   
      if (marker === 'startMarker') {
         array.push({ marker: true, value })
      } else if (marker === 'endMarker') {
         array.push({ marker: false, value })
      }
   
      text = text.slice(markerEnd + value.length + 1)
   }
   
   return array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const escapeRegex = s => s.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");

const extract = (start, end, str) => Array.from(
  str.matchAll(`(.+?)(${escapeRegex(start)}|${escapeRegex(end)}|$)`),
  ([, text, mark]) => ({
    marker: mark === end,
    value: text.trim()
  })
);

console.log(extract(
  "{startMarker}",
  "{endMarker}",
  "This is {startMarker} the string {endMarker} for {startMarker} example. {endMarker}"
));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGWQDc4AbAVwgC5kBnMKUAcwBoCiBbOKAa2loAjAPbCyEOCAIBfAgQTCQDZBDoI4ABwgAlCMwgAPZAF5kACjq0GTEMwCUJgHz0AdFAgayiCGYD0AbRcAKgBqAB0AWgB+AD0AEmxpMzsAH38wgF0wzN82ZAAibLiAMny7AG45fAUlMBUDRkQ60wtMKDBqaxZWFRAAE07GbvpGKyHbB2NnAEEoKDgATxcYKGFOMw4RqBduMAQAC2myMjMQCAB3ZF1mAFEDDTMAAzMXEKi7MwTVdS1rw1aeGA7NIUl81JodHp-hB+sDQXZHj18swynYer5fAAVBZaADKCCYGjqggozGQEWQC2EFGQ+zgxBQYGEyA0cDodGQWGudw0yGEggAVhAEGAeiBhHUsF1bJszP4epAGj1uHwMnZaOhME5zHhCERkCr+FBaIaTMZTDC+uw9URSJQaMhFWAXEN1nZNtJ3fgKlUanQxBAXGRhMwzIZGiKNnr8tgGICALI8I3SfLWogxy2JvjQFNpgqY-bADlFnBx9pZ5OO-YoaVk7CZpM55AwYRQUttMAVpuGOCcTyBnAN7NQFMEOwVIA)

## Explanation

### Regex

We text segments that end with one of two markers. We can extract each section including the mark.

```
This is {startMarker} the string {endMarker} 
^______^^___________^^__________^^_________^
| text       mark   ||   text        mark  |
^___________________^^_____________________^
       section               section
```

The text will become the `value` of the result object, the marker segment can be checked if it's `{endMarker}` in order to produce `true` or `false` for the result object.

So, if we could extract the segments and sections correctly, the result is:

```
result = {
  marker: marker === "{endMarker}",
  value: text.trim()
}
```

A regular expression that will do this for us is:

```
/(.+?)(\{startMarker\}|\{endMarker\}|$)/g
```

[See on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/H9ATW9/1)

- `(.+?)` will match and capture text segment
- `(\{startMarker\}|\{endMarker\}|$)` will match and extract marker at the end of the text segment. It also matches the end of the line in case there is more text after the last mark, like if you have `for {startMarker} example. {endMarker} more text here`

#### Generation

To be more general, we can take *any* string for start and end marker then escape them to make sure they match literally, even if there are meta characters like `.` or `*` in them. I've taken the [escape function from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping) and converted it to an arrow function for brevity:

```
const escapeRegex = s => s.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
```

This way we can take `start` and `end` as strings and generate a regular expression using [the `RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
const escapeRegex = s => s.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");

const start = "{startMarker}";
const end = "{endMarker}";

const regex = new RegExp(`(.+?)(${escapeRegex(start)}|${escapeRegex(end)}|$)`, "g");

console.log(regex.toString());
```

#### Matching

The [`String#matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) method will produce [an iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterators) which contains all the matches from that regular expression applied to the string.

```js
const escapeRegex = s => s.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");

const extract = (start, end, str) => {
  const sequence = str.matchAll(`(.+?)(${escapeRegex(start)}|${escapeRegex(end)}|$)`);
  
  for(const result of sequence) {
    console.log(result);
  }
};

extract(
  "{startMarker}",
  "{endMarker}",
  "This is {startMarker} the string {endMarker} for {startMarker} example. {endMarker}"
);
```

The `.matchAll()` method accepts a string as a prameter and will automatically convert it to a regex using the `RegExp` constructor and will further automatically add the global flag. However, TypeScript currently seems to not allow that - the typing for the method only allow a `RegExp` object, so for TypeScript only (until the typing is fixed) you have to call

```typescript
str.matchAll(new RegExp(`(.+?)(${escapeRegex(start)}|${escapeRegex(end)}|$)`, "g"))
```

### Convert to array

The easiest way to convert an iterable to an array is by using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). The first parameter it takes can be an iterable and it's automatically converted to an array. The second parameter is a mapping function to be applied before each element is put in the array.

Since we receive regex match results, we can directly convert them to the needed items with this function:

```
result => {
  const match = result[1];
  const marker = result[2];

  return {
    marker: marker === end,
    value: match.trim()
  };
}
```

Which gives us the more verbose version:

```js
const escapeRegex = s => s.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");

const extract = (start, end, str) => {
  return Array.from(
    str.matchAll(`(.+?)(${escapeRegex(start)}|${escapeRegex(end)}|$)`),
    result => {
      const match = result[1];
      const marker = result[2];

      return {
        marker: marker === end,
        value: match.trim()
      };
    }
  );
}

console.log(extract(
  "{startMarker}",
  "{endMarker}",
  "This is {startMarker} the string {endMarker} for {startMarker} example. {endMarker}"
));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGWQDc4AbAVwgC5kBnMKUAcwBoCiBbOKAa2loAjAPbCyEOCAIBfAgQTCQDZBDoI4ABwgAlCMwgAPZAF5kACjq0GTEMwCUJgHz0AdFAgayiCGYD0AbRcAKgBqAB0AWgB+AD0AEmxpMzsAH38wgF0wzN82ZAAibLiAMny7AG45fBgKEAQwYEUVA0ZEMAtMKDArRhZWFRAAEx6bPOsRlgc8fABIBSUwZHd9I1MQCAB3ZF1mAFEDDTMAAzMXEKi7MwTVdS0dww6eMDtpFOu1TR09B4ghl7e7Ed+vlmGVKvgCDN3GAKFAQMgAIJQKBwACeLhgUGEnDMkJm1hc3DACAAFgiyGQzMtDHZ2LMZlTVBQyM9aOhME4cHi5oplETSSYlkyWf4AIwZcEzKXzPk8fhQQXuOjMsD+ABMEu50Nh8OmUql3D4AmQhvlJmMpl+gzp+pmpEoNBNGFJLl6OLs3OkkpmslmFRkVRlYggLjIwmYZkMrXquNm+WwDCeAFk5dBpPkbfGrSmjVB05mACok4B0ZAlnCJro5+XSZBgEkoawsHDZ1N55AwYQKhOdMDVtPNOCcTwhltDft5-IEOz+-BAA)

However, we can reduce the code needed via [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and it becomes.

```
([, text, mark]) => ({
  marker: mark === end,
  value: text.trim()
})
```

Which finally gives us the initial bit of code from the top (included again, to avoid scrolling back up):

```js
const escapeRegex = s => s.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");

const extract = (start, end, str) => Array.from(
  str.matchAll(`(.+?)(${escapeRegex(start)}|${escapeRegex(end)}|$)`),
  ([, text, mark]) => ({
    marker: mark === end,
    value: text.trim()
  })
);

console.log(extract(
  "{startMarker}",
  "{endMarker}",
  "This is {startMarker} the string {endMarker} for {startMarker} example. {endMarker}"
));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGWQDc4AbAVwgC5kBnMKUAcwBoCiBbOKAa2loAjAPbCyEOCAIBfAgQTCQDZBDoI4ABwgAlCMwgAPZAF5kACjq0GTEMwCUJgHz0AdFAgayiCGYD0AbRcAKgBqAB0AWgB+AD0AEmxpMzsAH38wgF0wzN82ZAAibLiAMny7AG45fAUlMBUDRkQ60wtMKDBqaxZWFRAAE07GbvpGKyHbB2NnAEEoKDgATxcYKGFOMw4RqBduMAQAC2myMjMQCAB3ZF1mAFEDDTMAAzMXEKi7MwTVdS1rw1aeGA7NIUl81JodHp-hB+sDQXZHj18swynYer5fAAVBZaADKCCYGjqggozGQEWQC2EFGQ+zgxBQYGEyA0cDodGQWGudw0yGEggAVhAEGAeiBhHUsF1bJszP4epAGj1uHwMnZaOhME5zHhCERkCr+FBaIaTMZTDC+uw9URSJQaMhFWAXEN1nZNtJ3fgKlUanQxBAXGRhMwzIZGiKNnr8tgGICALI8I3SfLWogxy2JvjQFNpgqY-bADlFnBx9pZ5OO-YoaVk7CZpM55AwYRQUttMAVpuGOCcTyBnAN7NQFMEOwVIA)

### Final note about ES2020 compatibility

`String#matchAll` comes from the ES2020 specs. If you're not currently targetting that and don't want to, you can very easily roll your own version using a generator function that will work very similarly:

```
function* matchAll(pattern, text) {
  const regex = typeof pattern === "string"
    ? new RegExp(pattern, "g")  //convert to global regex
    : new RegExp(pattern);      //or make a copy of the regex object to avoid mutating the input
    
  let result;
  while(result = regex.exec(text)) //apply `regex.exec` repeatedly
    yield result;                  //and produce each result from the iterator
}
```

The only notable omission here is that `String#matchAll` will thrown an error if a non-global regex object is passed in. It can still be implemented but I went with a slightly shorter implementation for illustration.

Using the custom `matchAll` you can target versions prior to ES2020 without needing a polyfill

```js
const escapeRegex = s => s.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");

function* matchAll(pattern, text) {
  const regex = typeof pattern === "string"
    ? new RegExp(pattern, "g")
    : new RegExp(pattern);
    
  let result;
  while(result = regex.exec(text))
    yield result;
}

const extract = (start, end, str) => Array.from(
  matchAll(`(.+?)(${escapeRegex(start)}|${escapeRegex(end)}|$)`, str),
  ([, text, mark]) => ({
    marker: mark === end,
    value: text.trim()
  })
);

console.log(extract(
  "{startMarker}",
  "{endMarker}",
  "This is {startMarker} the string {endMarker} for {startMarker} example. {endMarker}"
));
```

[Playground Link with target set to ES2015](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGWQDc4AbAVwgC5kBnMKUAcwBoCiBbOKAa2loAjAPbCyEOCAIBfAgQTCQDZBDoI4ABwgAlCMwgAPZAF5kACjq0GTEMwCUJgHz0AdFAgayiCGYD0AbRcAKgBqAB0AWgB+AD0AEmxpMzsAH38wgF0wzN82ZAAibLiAMny7AG45fBgKEAQwYEUg5G4wBAALAEEyMjMNDEgoECtGFmQU5F1mAFEDDVZkSAMwEZt7HA5kBSUwZHd9I1MwAE8tYRhkfrBBkBNjU3zrFnzNoijkEAgAd0m9WY0+gNoCAFvlmGVXshaJ8flN-oDrsCKpDNuJdu46BQyGBKoRkF92sBxGYMVjdqZ9oYXIYIAgzEswHY7JDjsAIGQACZ7VRk3GyfDyRTKQyMRDk8wMHgreijWwLCAgDmrFgLazK2wOYzOTpQKBwY4uGBQYScMybVodbq9AAGZhcISidjMCVU6i0U0MFkwUEZ0hSLrUmh0ek9Co5dj9cTs1tVjDs7DxZn8CwZC24fAydlo6EwRC15jweK4PH4UFo6d4d1MYYTRCIpEoNEWIpco1NzLx0g7yIF+G2dDEEBcZGEzDMIr19TNePy2ElPoAsiXoNJ8rWCtgw0u+Cu15t8gAVQl0ZDAE9z71gbel6SLdooJ62HBb5dQW8wYRQHDzq+v2+GOBOE8Idn0Va9dwIJlyiAA)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the response and the informations !